# onkeyup or onkeypress only after X characters length

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is anyway to call a js function only when we fill a number of characters characters on a textfield?

from now im using onblur="myFunction();" but i wants to cal that function after we have some characters filled.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `onkeyup` event:

```
let element = document.querySelector('your element');
element.onkeyup = function () {
    if (this.value.length > 10) {
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

You also use this in an attribute:

```
<textarea onkeyup="if (this.value.length > 10) myFunction();"></textarea>
```

[**EXAMPLE (for both)**](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/B95jE/)

Comment: adding JavaScript as HTML attribute is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Even in 2019 I still had to use this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
/* go automatic do the next tabindex */ 

$(":input:not(:disabled)").not($(":button")).keyup(function(evt){
if (this.value.length == 1) {
    currentTabindex = $(this).attr('tabindex');
            if (currentTabindex) {
                nextInput = $('input[tabindex^="'+ (parseInt(currentTabindex)+1) +'"]');
                if (nextInput.length) {
                    nextInput.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
}
});
```